# I want to test CoreBluetooth library on IOS Simulator (sdk6.1, sdk7)

Tags: ios-simulator, core-bluetooth

i searched and found following CSR USB BLE adapters.
It would be better if i buy this?- http://usb.brando.com/bluetooth-csr-4-0-dongle_p02926c036d015.html
http://cirago.com/wordpress/products/bluetoothadapters/bluetooth-4-0-mini-usb-adapter/
Somebody suggest me better option.

Comment: I should note that they removed Core Bluetooth support in the Simulator as of iOS 7, so you won't be able to do anything with the Simulator for that SDK version. For older versions, you'll want to read this Apple tech note: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2295/_index.html

Comment: Do you have any reference for (or even idea why) the iOS 7 removal?